# wordpress ajaxurl to fetch backbone model

Tags: javascript, wordpress, backbone.js

I'm learning Backbone.js and trying to build simple theme based on it. I have in functions.php this code to load js:

```
    function load_js() {
      wp_enqueue_script('app-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/app.js', array('backbone'));
      wp_localize_script('app-js', 'mechanics', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js');
```

And in app.js this simple code to fetch posts:

```
(function($){
    var Post = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    var Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: Post,
            url: mechanics.ajaxurl
    });

    var new_posts = new Posts;
    new_posts.fetch();
})
```

Server side works (I've tested it with jquery). If think problem is with url statement. Can someone tell me how it should look or if there is a difference between jQuery ajax and Backbone sync url?

Working jQuery version

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var $ = jQuery;

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: mechanics.ajaxurl,
    data: { action : 'mechanics_get_posts' },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function( response ) {
        alert( response );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you show the JS code you used that did work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I needed to add data to fetch function. Final code looks like this:

```
var Post = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Post,
    url: mechanics.ajaxurl
});

var new_posts = new Posts;
new_posts.fetch({
    data: { action: 'mechanics_get_posts' }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: Make sure Underscore and jQuery are loaded.**

Backbone.$ = jQuery, so Backbone.fetch() is jQuery.ajax({type: "GET"});

Your url property in your collection should be a string. I'm not familiar with mechanics, so if "mechanics.ajaxurl" is on the window object as a string and **points to a valid endpoint, which returns JSON,** it should work.

Change:

```
var new_posts = new Posts;
```

To:

```
var new_posts = new Posts();
```

Then, as with `$.ajax`, in your `fetch()` method you can do the following:

```
new_posts.fetch({
  success: function(collection, object, jqXHR) {
    your code...
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, statusText, error) {
    your code...
  }
});
```

Comment: It didn't work. Checked with FireBug and didn't see any request. "mechanics" is my theme name and namespace declared with load_js function

Comment: I just caught this but, do you have Underscore loaded as well as jQuery? They need to be loaded before Backbone. Underscore is a "hard dependency." If you do have these loaded and it's still not working, can you break point at the url attribute to see what the url string is?